# Nlog config escape colon

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, nlog

I have a NLog.config file with the following variable

```
<variables>
    <variable name="LogsFilePath" value="${appsetting:item=LogsFolderPath:default=C:\Company\Logs}" >
</variables>
<targets>
    
    <target name="File"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${LogsFilePath}\${event-properties:FileName}.log" />
    
</targets>

<rules>
    <rule logger="DynamicLogger_*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="File" />
</rules>
```

When there is no value in `app.config` file the default value taken is only `C` (because of the colon).

My target is something like this

Also if I use the variable in the config file like `${var:LogsFilePath}` I have problems because of the colon. I have to use it with the static form `${LogsFilePath}`

How can I solve this and use a path as default value in the default path of the `appsetting` variable?

Comment: It works when me when adding escapes: `value="${appsetting:item=LogsFolderPath:default=C\:\\Company\\Logs}"`. Alternative then one can use whenEmpty. `value="${appsetting:item=LogsFolderPath:whenEmpty=C\:\\Company\\Logs}"`. (Ofcourse the fallback requires that you have valid file-permission to write files on the C-drive)

Comment: Maybe also add fallback for fileName like this: `fileName="${LogsFilePath}\${event-properties:FileName:whenEmpty=App}.log"`. Consider using [NLog GDC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer) instead of NLog LogEvent-Properties for the Filename. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context

Comment: @RolfKristensen I'm using properties because I want to use same target for different loggers created dynamically and I want to have the possibility to specify filename. In my code I create loggers with name "DynamicLogger_*" and them I set the property for file name. I have edited the question with the rules part. I'm not sure if GDC is valid for that because it's dynamic.

Comment: If you do this `NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("DynamicLogger.MyFileName")` with this `<rule logger="DynamicLogger.*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="File" />`, then you can specify FileName like this: `fileName="${LogsFilePath}\${logger:shortName=true}.log"` See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer (Removing the need to include FileName in LogEvent Properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape it. Replace ":" with "\:", also you need to escape backslash.

I got it working like this

```
<variables>
    <variable name="LogsFolderPath" value="${appsetting:item=LogsFolderPath:default=C\:\\Company\\Logs}" />
</variables>
```

Comment: on StackOverflow you need to escape them too, fixed. Also double dots is called colon

Comment: So I have to put C\:\Company\Logs. correct?

Comment: yes its correct

Comment: I think this is not working because it's trying to save logs in C:\log.log, so it is not taking the complete path

Comment: oh, looks like you need to escape backslash too

Comment: I have try with C\\:\\Company\\Logs and also with C\:\\Company\\Logs No one is working I have a permission exception beause it could not write in C

Comment: try to use ${appsetting:item=LogsFolderPath:default=${literal:text=C\:\\Company\\Logs}}"